# CSS styles for an ID'd div not taking effect

Tags: html, css

With this markup (it's nested within other containers)

```
<div id="#club-solutions">
<h2>We Have The Solutions</h2>
<h3>OUR PROGRAMS</h3>
<p>Our programs will keep your classes packed and your members on their toes.</p>
```

Why would the following CSS not be applied?

```
#club-solutions h3 {
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

#club-solutions p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#club-solutions a {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

- The stylesheet they're in is being applied to the markup and when I change other styles on the stylesheet the other changes take effect.
- I have cacheing completely switched off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `#` (in `<div id="#club-solutions">`) is an invalid character for an ID.

Without it, it works fine: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HGEsd/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="club-solutions">
```

`#` belongs to the CSS only (it is used to indicate that an ID follows).

Answer (score 1):

Change `<div id="#club-solutions">` to `<div id="club-solutions">`

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the "#" in HTML.It's illegal.